# Tabs on action collapse because the title takes too much room. What can I do?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

Because of my long app name (and other factors) the 4 tabs that I have are now collapsed. This happens on devices using large-layout. In portrait mode, it looks like the picture above. However, in landscape mode, there is plenty of room for the name and 4 tabs.

I already tried deleting the title but the tabs are still collapsed. How do I make it so that the tabs always show and if there is no room, have it hide the app name. I'd rather not have ellipses (App Name Go...). I'd rather just hide the title completely. I need this specifically for large-layout in portrait mode.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this, fisrt add tabs after that set navigation mode. Like this,

```
    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
//dont set navigation mode now.
bar.setLogo(logo);
bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

// Now add tabs
    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = bar.newTab();
    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = bar.newTab();
    ActionBar.Tab tab3 = bar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("Packages");
    tab1.setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_menu_share_holo_dark);
    tab2.setText("Blogs");
    tab2.setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_voice_search);
    tab3.setText("Gallery");
    tab3.setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_cab_done_holo_dark);

    tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener());
    tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener());
    tab3.setTabListener(new MyTabListener());
    bar.addTab(tab1);
    bar.addTab(tab2);
    bar.addTab(tab3);
```

// Now set navigation mode

```
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not control when action bar tabs are collapsed. That is up to Android. I filed [an issue about this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24439) that was rejected.

If you absolutely cannot have the collapsed UI, switch to a `ViewPager` and either `PagerTabStrip`, the tab indicator from ViewPagerIndicator, or any other `ViewPager` tab implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Action Bar will collapse tabs by default when area available is less. In portrait view, it creates another tab panel below the Action Bar. You can force this behavior in landscape mode also:

```
 try {
        Class c = Class.forName("com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl");
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs",boolean.class);
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(getActionBar(),false); //-- do not embed tabs --
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Note:** This is a reflection hack, and underlying private class can change in future versions.